# Show full calculation in Mathematica to copy into latex

Tags: latex, wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha, mathematica-8, wolfram-language

I'm new to Mathematica I was hoping that this is a functionality built in.  I am calculating the conditional entropy of a table and have the following 4 variables:

```
a = 1/8*Log[(1/8)/(1/2)] + 1/16*Log[(1/16)/(1/2)] + 1/16*Log[(1/16)/(1/2)] + 1/4*Log[(1/4)/(1/2)]

b = 1/16*Log[(1/16)/(1/4)] + 1/8*Log[(1/8)/(1/4)] + 1/32*Log[(1/32)/(1/4)] + 0

c = 1/32*Log[(1/32)/(1/8)] + 1/32*Log[(1/32)/(1/8)] + 1/16*Log[(1/16)/(1/8)] + 0

d = 1/32*Log[(1/32)/(1/8)] + 1/32*Log[(1/32)/(1/8)] + 1/32*Log[(1/32)/(1/8)] + 0
```

Then the final calculation is:

```
a + b + c + d
```

I was hoping there was a way to display the expanded `a + b + c + d` as a output so I can right-click/copy as latex to past into a document so I don't have to type it out.  I can't figure out how to do it though.  I'm guessing there is a way to expand those variables in the output to show the full calculation but maybe it is not possible.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: One small step at a time. If you enter each of your four lines and follow each by Enter and then you enter a+b+c+d and follow that by Enter then does that display the sum you want? Mathematica is an "infinite evaluation" system, where it applies all the previous information and rules it has, perhaps again and again, until the result doesn't change. Does that a+b+c+d line display the total in the form you want? If not then please edit your post to show what it displays instead and what needs to change. Note that Mathematica keeps a cache of prior assignments till you exit or tell it to forget.

Comment: By the way, you might find [Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) to be a helpful site for future Mathematica/Wolfram Language questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how expanded you wanted the mathematical expression to be. See if the following expression is in the form you want to convert to LaTeX: `(1/16 Log[1/(16/4)]+1/8 Log[1/(8/4)]+1/32 Log[1/(32/4)]+0)+(1/32 Log[1/(32/8)]+1/32 Log[1/(32/8)]+1/16 Log[1/(16/8)]+0)+(1/32 Log[1/(32/8)]+1/32 Log[1/(32/8)]+1/32 Log[1/(32/8)]+0)+(1/8 Log[1/(8/2)]+1/16 Log[1/(16/2)]+1/16 Log[1/(16/2)]+1/4 Log[1/(4/2)])`.

You can get that by using HoldForm on the right-hand side of your assignments. Then use `TeXForm[a+b+c+d]` to convert:

```js
a = HoldForm[
  1/8*Log[(1/8)/(1/2)] + 1/16*Log[(1/16)/(1/2)] + 
   1/16*Log[(1/16)/(1/2)] + 1/4*Log[(1/4)/(1/2)]];

b = HoldForm[
  1/16*Log[(1/16)/(1/4)] + 1/8*Log[(1/8)/(1/4)] + 
   1/32*Log[(1/32)/(1/4)] + 0];

c = HoldForm[
   1/32*Log[(1/32)/(1/8)] + 1/32*Log[(1/32)/(1/8)] + 
    1/16*Log[(1/16)/(1/8)] + 0];

d = HoldForm[
   1/32*Log[(1/32)/(1/8)] + 1/32*Log[(1/32)/(1/8)] + 
    1/32*Log[(1/32)/(1/8)] + 0];

TeXForm[a + b + c + d]
```